# Can cmake handle rc files?

Tags: gcc, visual-studio-code, cmake, g++, rc

Can cmake handle rc files?
There is a project that needs to be converted from msvc to  g++ compilation.
Compiling with cmake can be successful, but after the program starts, it exits directly without a screen.

Comment: Yes, CMake is able to handle rc (resource) files. According the [CMake maillist](https://cmake.org/pipermail/cmake/2006-August/010917.html), `.rc` files are simply added to `add_executable` call as sources. If you project doesn't work, then it could be problems with the project's code. So, for being able to help you we need to see that code. Note, that we don't wont your original code, which could be large, secret, and so on. What you need to provide is [mcve].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just  put the rc file and the resource file in some folder,cmake will handle it automaticlly.